# Mac OS X: "A keychain cannot be found to store [credentials]"

Tags: macos, git, keychain

I'm trying to use git with a remote repo over the command line in OS X 10.8.4. When I enter my credentials for GitHub every time I perform a `git push -u origin master`, I get a system saying "A keychain cannot be found to store [my GitHub credentials]." I'm given the option to reset my keychain or continue without storing the creds.

I tried following the instructions [given on Apple's site for this situation](https://support.apple.com/kb/TS1530?viewlocale=en_US) – although they're a bit outdated.

When I try to reset my keychain, I'm prompted for my login password, which is systematically rejected by the authentication dialog.

I've never had this kind of issue; what's the cause, and how can it be fixed?

Shown in the Keychain Access app:

- Login
- System
- System roots

In the ~/LIbrary/Preferences file:

```
login.keychain
metadata.keychain
two hidden files with seemingly random alphanumeric names
```

The permissions for ~/Library/Preferences are

```
-rw-r--r--
```

For my personal account, and no permissions are shown for root upon `ls -l`. This may be the root of the problem; I was trying to push using root.

Comment: What keychain files do you have in your library? What are that folder's permissions? What gets shown in the *Keychain Access* app?

Comment: @DanielBeck Updated my question with that info.

Comment: Are you in a root shell when running `git`? If so, that's the issue. You probably shouldn't do that unless you have a really good reason. *Maybe* you'd succeed by creating `/var/root/Library/Keychains` (that's root's home directory) and copying an empty keychain there.

Comment: I just tried performing `git push -u origin master` on the same directory from my (non-root) login shell, and got the same error.

Comment: It might also depend on how you entered the root shell. `sudo -s` keeps your regular user's `$HOME`, while `su`/`sudo su` does not.

Comment: Anything interesting in logged in the *Console* application?

Comment: Nothing interesting; in fact, nothing remotely related to git at all.

Comment: How did you fix this? I got the same problem all of a sudden...

Comment: @AeroWindwalker this was 7 years ago, I don't remember what the fix was — and odds are any fix is at this point outdated. Sorry.